# Executar método/função ao carregar página

Tags: jquery

**Não é duplicada dessa**: [Como executar uma script jquery ao carregar uma pagina](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/237136/como-executar-uma-script-jquery-ao-carregar-uma-pagina)

---

Tenho uma função que lista um conteúdo numa `div`:

```
function listar() {
    alert("listar"); // alert para saber se está sendo chamado
    arquivo = "lista.php";
    $.ajax({
        url:arquivo,
        success: function (textStatus) {      
            $('#iddiv1').html(textStatus);
        }
    }); 
}
```

---

**Tentei** carregar essa função junto da página, mas não dá certo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    listar();
});
```

---

Também, gostaria que, **enquanto executar** o método `listar()`, fique oculta a `div`.

Exemplo:

```
$('#iddiv1').hide();
$('#iddiv2').show();
```

Tentei assim, mas sem sucesso:

```
$('#iddiv1').load(function() {
    $('#iddiv1').hide();
    $('#iddiv2').show();
});
```

Comment: Pq não cria a função já dentro do **document.ready**?

Comment: @LeAndrade Não é o exemplo que eu tentei? Ou está errado?

Comment: Está carregando o jQuery antes de chamar o  `$(document).ready(function(){`? Se não, provavelmente tem um erro no console.

Comment: @sam a `<script>` da função está na `<head>` e o `<script>` do jquery, no fim da `<body>`... Tem que ser inversa a ordem?

Comment: @sam é isso mesmo... carregando! 

Comment: Vc pode deixar na ordem que quiser se trocar o `$(document).ready(function(){` por `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente está chamando o evento `$(document).ready(function(){` antes de carregar o jQuery, e com isso resultando em erro, pois o `$(document).ready` é um evento jQuery.

Neste caso você tem 2 alternativas:

Ou chamar o `$(document).ready(function(){` após o `<script>` que carrega o jQuery (após não quer dizer *logo após*. Após em qualquer lugar, desde que seja depois):

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    listar();
});
</script>
```

Ou usar o evento nativo do JavaScript em qualquer lugar do código, antes ou depois de carregar o jQuery:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   listar();
});
</script>
```

---

O método `.load()` é usado para carregar conteúdo HTML a um elemento (uma `div`, por exemplo), não para detectar o carregamento da página.

Neste caso você pode executar o código após o retorno do Ajax, no `success:`:

```
success: function (textStatus) {      
   $('#iddiv1').html(textStatus).hide();
   $('#iddiv2').show();
}
```

Comment: O sam, e o hide/show da div ?!  Abro outra pergunta?

Comment: Resposta atualizada.